# Куда вводить команды компилятора gnu fortran (minGw) + CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, fortran, gnu

Изучаю фортран по книге "Chapman: Fortran 95/2003 for Scientists and Engineers, Third Edition". В 6 главе (про массивы)
говорится, что в компиляторах фортрана можно включить проверку выхода за границу массива:

> Always turn on the bounds checking option on your Fortran compiler during program development and debugging to help you catch programming errors producing out-of-bounds references. The bounds-checking option may be turned off if necessary for greater speed in the final program.

Проверил на своем компиляторе (GNU Fortran Compller) — у меня опция проверки выхода за границу массива выключена.

Что нужно нажать, какую консоль запускать, чтобы в ней вводить управляющие команды для откл./вкл. опций компилятора? 
(в частности нужно включить опцию проверки выхода за границу массива в компиляторе)

Использую среду Code Blocks + MinGw ( GNU Fortran Compller).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В меню выбираете Settings - Compiler..., там появится окно, в котором надо вверху выбрать GNU Fortran Compiler, а чуть ниже поставить галочку Run-time check for array subscripts:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем необходимо пересобрать проект.

Comment: Спасибо большое, @Wildcat , за помощь. Теперь стало ясно как можно менять параметры компилятора.

Answer (score 1):

согласно [документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html), компилятору надо передать опцию

```
-fcheck=bounds
```

> Enable generation of run-time checks for array subscripts and against the declared minimum and maximum values.

мой вольный перевод:

> Разрешить генерацию контроля времени выполнения для индексов массивов и объявленных минимального и максимального значений.

---

по поводу *codeblocks*: вероятно, вручную указать опции компилятора можно где-то в районе закладки «other options» (на стрелку внимания не обращайте — это просто картинка, найденная в сети):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, @alexander barakin, за помощь.